# Averaging compound interest rates is returning an unexpected result

Tags: average

Let's consider two stocks with the following prices for a three days period:

```
Stock 1:
 day 1: 100
 day 2: 105
 day 3: 110

Stock 2:
 day 1:100
 day 2:100
 day 3:110
```

The increase percentage each time for stocks 1 and 2 are respectively:

```
Stock 1: [5% , 4,761904761904761904761904762%]
Stock 2: [0% , 10%]
```

When I average the two stocks increase percentage, I get:

```
  Avg Stock growth: [2,5% , 7,38095238095238095238095238%]
```

The problem is when I try to compute back the price of both stock combined together, with an initial price of 100, to reflect the scenario of investing equally in both stocks:

```
Day 1: 100
Day 2: 102.5 (100 + 100*2.5%)
Day 3: 110.0654761904761904761904762 (102.5 + 102.5*7,38095238095238095238095238%)
The end result does not add up to 110 but to 110.06 (...) which is not something I expected.
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Note that I'm using python to compute results

Comment: To see why this kind of naïve averaging of each day's interest rates in isolation cannot _possibly_ work, consider the following two scenarios: in scenario A, stock 1 goes up by +900% each day while stock 2 goes down by -90% each day; in scenario B, the same thing happens on the first day but then the rates reverse, so that stock 1 now goes down by -90% while stock 2 goes up by +900%. In scenario A, an initial investment of \$100 in each stock on day 1 will have grown to \$10000 + \$1 = \$10001 by day 3; in scenario B, you'll just get your original \$200 back.

Comment: Averaging percentages when the base of each percentage is different is meaningless and can't give the correct result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When taking average of the two stocks increases, you should also consider the investment ratio by value between the two stocks.

After day 2, the investment ratio is no longer $1:1$ as in day 1, but becomes $105:100 = 21:20$. Then when taking weighted average of the stock increases from day 2 to day 3,

$$\begin{align*}
\text{Weighted avg stock growth} &= \frac{21\cdot \frac{110-105}{105} + 20\cdot \frac{110-100}{100}}{21+20}\\
&= \frac{(110-105)+(110-100)}{105+100}\\
&\approx 7.317\%
\end{align*}$$

This matches the combined portfolio growth from day 2 to day 3:

$$\begin{align*}
\text{Portfolio growth} &= \frac{\frac12 (110+110)-\frac12 (105+100)}{\frac12 (105+100)}\\
&= \frac{110-102.5}{102.5}\\
&\approx 7.317\%
\end{align*}$$

Comment: ah That makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

With combined stocks, the two stocks become as one, so the data becomes

```
200
205
220
```

Your required percentage is now $\frac{220-205}{205}=7.317073170\dots\%$.